# Installing vpnc on CentOS

Tags: centos, software-installation, vpn

I'm currently attempting to establish a vpn connection, but I am unable to install a vpn client.  I assumed installation would be as simple as `sudo yum install vpnc`, but CentOS is unable to find the vpnc package.

I browsed some more, and discovered I needed to install and enable the rpmforge repository for yum to find the package.  I downloaded the rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm and installed successfully.  However, when I run my original yum command, I am still unable to find the package.

Is there a different repository I need to add in order to locate the vpnc packages for CentOS 6.3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [EPEL repository](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) has a `vpnc` package. Generally, EPEL should be the first place you should look for additional packages. The EPEL repository is semi-official, since it is from the Fedora project. Unlike rpmforge, it doesn't contain any packages that already exist in CentOS/RHEL, so you do not need to worry about conflicts.

Instructions on setting up the EPEL repository can be found [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F). Optionally, you can manually download the [rpm](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/vpnc.html).

Comment: great thanks @jordanm, just what I was looking for.