# install cisco VPN client on linux

Tags: linux, vpn, cisco

I am currently using Windows XP with Cisco VPN Client version 5.0.01.0600

I would like to replace Windows XP with Linux, either Red Hat version 5.x or 6.x

My question is, what equivalent VPN software can I install on Linux machine in order to get full compatibility with the same VPN network that the Cisco VPN client uses.

Where can I download Cisco VPN Client version 5.0.01.0600 for Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Note that Cisco VPN Client is [end of life software](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/vpn-client/end_of_life_c51-680819.html) and all support for it will end this July. There does not appear to be a Linux version for 5.x, however the 4.x Linux version can be downloaded [here](http://software.cisco.com/download/release.html?mdfid=281940729&flowid=4465&softwareid=282364316&os=Linux&release=4.8.02.0030&relind=AVAILABLE&rellifecycle=&reltype=latest). The Free Software alternative that gives (some?) of the same functionality as Cisco VPN Client is [vpnc](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/).

The replacement for the Cisco VPN Client software is Cisco AnyConnect, for which there are download links [here](http://software.cisco.com/download/release.html?mdfid=283000185&flowid=17001&softwareid=282364313&release=3.1.05160&relind=AVAILABLE&rellifecycle=&reltype=latest). This may be what you need (although I have little knowledge on how the techologies differ). If this *is* the case, then the Free Software alternative is [OpenConnect](http://software.cisco.com/download/release.html?mdfid=283000185&flowid=17001&softwareid=282364313&release=3.1.05160&relind=AVAILABLE&rellifecycle=&reltype=latest).

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with `vpnc`. According to this question:

[Installing vpnc on CentOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61691/installing-vpnc-on-centos)

You can find a package in the EPEL package repository.